# Thumbnail image should be swapped with the current image on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have a codepen link https://codepen.io/robgolbeck/pen/bVGmop which is quite similar to what I want. The only thing I want is that on click of thumbs image the large image should be replaced with the clicked thumbs image and it should not be present in the thumbs list.In total only 5 images should be present in rotation whereas here there are 6(5+ 1repeated in thumbs). I have tried to tweak the JS but it doesn't work as expected. Can anyone please help. Stuck with this problem since morning. Thanks in advance.

JS

```
$('#thumbs img').click(function(){
  $('#largeImage').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb','large'));
  $(this).attr('src',$('#largeImage').attr('src').replace('large','thumb'));
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the click handler event of `#thumbs img`, you can first show all the images and then hide current image. to start you can trigger click on first image.

```
$('#thumbs img').click(function(){
  $('#largeImage').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb','large'));
  $('#description').html($(this).attr('alt'));
  $('#thumbs img').show();
  $(this).hide();
});
$('#thumbs img').first().trigger('click');
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Diij . This answer works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use jQuerys [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) methods. First show all child elements of `#thumbs` and then hide the currently clicked element with `$(this).hide();`.

To initially hide the first image, you can use `$('#thumbs').children().first().hide();`

```js
$('#thumbs').children().first().hide();
$('#thumbs img').click(function() {
  $('#largeImage').attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('thumb', 'large'));
  $('#description').html($(this).attr('alt'));
  $('#thumbs').children().show();
  $(this).hide();
});
```

```css
#thumbs {
  padding-top: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#thumbs img,
#largeImage {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#thumbs img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 6px;
}

#description {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  width: 525px;
  margin: 5px;
}

#panel {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="gallery">
  <div id="panel">
    <img id="largeImage" src="http://robgolbeck.com/demos/image-swap/image_01_large.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div id="thumbs">
    <img src="http://robgolbeck.com/demos/image-swap/image_01_thumb.jpg" alt="1st image description" />
    <img src="http://robgolbeck.com/demos/image-swap/image_02_thumb.jpg" alt="2nd image description" />
    <img src="http://robgolbeck.com/demos/image-swap/image_03_thumb.jpg" alt="3rd image description" />
    <img src="http://robgolbeck.com/demos/image-swap/image_04_thumb.jpg" alt="4th image description" />
    <img src="http://robgolbeck.com/demos/image-swap/image_05_thumb.jpg" alt="5th image description" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think **attr** method of jQuery is causing issue, try using **prop** method as shown in below snippet :

```
$('#thumbs img').click(function(){
   $('#largeImage').prop('src',$(this).prop('src').replace('thumb','large'));;
    $('#description').html($(this).prop('alt'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#thumbs img').click(function(){

    $("#thumbs img").each(function(){$(this).show();});
    $('#largeImage').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb','large'));
    $('#description').html($(this).attr('alt'));

    $(this).hide();
});
```